# Can't use Chrome/IE back button to return to Angular app

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have web app which contains a mix of new Angular pages using Html5Mode and legacy pages using classic ASP. We are in the process of converting the old pages, but in the meantime they continue to live side-by-side with the Angular app.

Links from the Angular app to ASP pages result in the back button not working in Chrome and IE. Clicking the back button simply rewrites the URL without navigating, leaving the user on the ASP page. I solved this problem in Firefox, by setting "cache-control: no-store no-cache", but Chrome and IE don't seem to respect these for the back button.

My external link is like this:

```
<a target="" ng-href="http://localhost:61887/A/B/C.asp" ng-bind="item.DisplayText" href="http://localhost:61887/A/B/C.asp">Classic Page</a>
```

Despite starting with "http://" the link is handling by angular routing (this itself seems odd). So it is handled by our otherwise route and our NonRoutedLocationCtrl:

```
commonControllers.controller('NonRoutedLocationCtrl', ["$location",
    function ($location) {
        console.log($location);
        window.location = $location.url();
    }
]);
```

Navigation to the ASP page is successful, but the back button doesn't work correctly. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Have you enabled the `HTML5` mode in angular app?

Comment: Yes, as  I stated in the question.

Comment: Are you using UI Router or ngRoute?

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?